# Need assistance using firebase streaming rest api not working

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, python-requests

Im trying to stream changes from my firebase database but the code i've written doesn't seem to be working. its not incurring errors, the stream is not closing as it is running throughout till i cancel the program but it isn't just yielding any results. its not showing any changes to my data. i've tried posting different data to the database to see if the stream would update but its not updating. if i remove the headers it works but it doesn't stream, i just get the data once and it closes. Below is my code. ill appreciate assistance

```
import requests
import json

headers = {"Accept": "text/event-stream"}
r = requests.get("https://************************************/messages/*******.json", stream= True, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)

if r.encoding is None:
   r.encoding = 'utf-8'

for line in r.iter_lines(decode_unicode=True):
   if line:
       print(json.loads(line))
```

Im following the instructions at the bottom of this page https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data. Thanks in advance